# NuGet выпуск своей библиотеки

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

Интересует вопрос. Есть ряд классов которые нацелены на решение одной проблемы - допустим работа с api cms/соц сети/и т.п. Как можно из этого собрать библиотеку и издать ее в NuGet. Как я правильно понимаю NuGet также поддерживает разные версии библиотеки. То есть каждое обновление библиотеки, публикуемое, так же доступно для скачивания пользователями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оригинальная статья из документации по созданию нюгета вручную:
http://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/creating-a-package

Прекрасная статья, которая описывает даже больше и лучше, чем задано в вопросе:
https://habrahabr.ru/post/274283/